# GUI not opening up from Jenkins service on Windows 7

Tags: user-interface, jenkins

I installed jenkins on Windows 7 machine as service.My application should open up GUI which is not coming.When I ran jenkins as war from cmd then application worked as expected with GUI also coming up which didn't happen from Jenkins service.
I  checked the option "Allow interaction with desktop" but it also was of no use.
Please suggest the option to run GUI application from Jenkins service on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

As Jenkins is running as a service, your GUI will be launched in a background process by your Jenkins job.

You won't be able to view it even if you choose the "Allow interaction with desktop"...

Comment: is there any way to open GUI with Jenkins installed as service?

Comment: Can't you run the war and the jenkins home page on the web browser in the same batch script ?

like 
java war - ...
start http://localhost:8080 ?

Comment: About your question for the GUI with the Windows service, it's not possible :(

Comment: Maybe you can have a look to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30707457/jenkins-cannot-run-firefox