# Not able to open JenkinsUI from slave machine when jenkins is installed via war package on master

Tags: jenkins

I do not have much experience with Jenkins and am facing a weird issue which has got me puzzled.

I have 2 machines say M1(master-Windows 10) and M2(slave-Windows 10) on the same network. I am able to ping M1 from M2 and vice-versa.

On M1, when I:

- install Jenkins as a Windows service, then **from M2**, I am able to access the JenkinsUI(via http://MachineName:8080)
- install Jenkins using the generic war package, then **from M2**, I **am not able** to access the JenkinsUI(via http://MachineName:8080)

Why I am not able to access the JenkinsUI from slave machine(M2) when I install Jenkins via war package even when the ping test is successful? Is there something I am missing? Has anyone ever faced such an issue before?

**Background:**
The reason I want to install Jenkins on M1 using the war package and not as a windows service is that I need to trigger my UI Test Automation Scripts on the slave machine, M2 which will not be triggered when Jenkins is installed as a service.([As mentioned in the comment section here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30369273/5331061))

**M1(Master):**

[image]

**M2(Slave - Not able to open Jenkins login page):**

[image]

Comment: Might be a windows firewall issue?

Comment: Not a firewall issue as the ping test is successful between the machines. Also, on installing jenkins as a window service, I was not facing this issue.

Comment: You can not check if access to a specific port (8080 here) is open with ping, its a different protocol that doesnt know ports (See [ICMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to open the Jenkins UI from a remote machine. I found the solution [HERE](https://superuser.com/a/1440248/1063161). As per the solution, I was only supposed to add the port to the Firewall.

I ran the following command in elevated mode on the machine where Jenkins was installed:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="TCP Port 8080" dir=in localport=8080 protocol=TCP action=allow
```

[image]