# Unable to open GUI Application through Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I'm new to Jenkins, I've created a Jenkins freestyle job used necessary plugins to invoke desktop application. When I execute the job with user credentials, I cannot see the application but application got up and logged on with user credentials. I'm doing GUI Automation which causes failures all the times when I try to run the job.

I created a batch file on HOST, calling the batch file through Jenkins. I have tried injecting the environment for job. I have enabled interactive services and Jenkins-slave on HOST machine. I tried to change NT/System user to Specific user. I enabled interactive services in both conditions. I'm not sure what I'm missing here. Do I need to install anything else, so far I have Jenkins-slave.exe on my HOST, I managed to generate executable Jar file using that. 
Any help on this will be appreciated.

I'm calling the batch file, Jenkins cannot find the application opening apparently, it returning error as None type Object(Python) as described in screenshot.[errors on Jenkins Job execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1u3U.png)

Comment: I'm using window7 ec2 instance as HOST

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I was trying to run Selenium UI Test on Windows Slave.
When the Slave is connected to Windows as a Service, then it does not bring up the application in foreground. It runs only in background even if you enable the service to interact with the desktop.

I had to change my browser to headless browser and then my test cases were passed in background mode.
[My Old Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56992731/unable-to-open-browser-when-running-selenium-test-in-windows-vms-from-jenkins)